# Why isn't 'for' loop iterating over list?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to write a cross-validation routine for a Lasso model in Python. I am dealing with time-series, so I am using the `TimeSeriesSplit` method from `sklearn`.

The dependent variable and regressors are denoted respectively by `Y` (numpy 1-dimensional array) and `F` (numpy nd-array) on my code. I'm applying LASSO to

> $ Y = F \beta + U$

in a very standard application. I'm using cross-validation to choose the penalty hyperparameter for LASSO. In order to do it, I define the following function in Python 3.6:

```
def optimal_penalty(Y, F, penalty_list, splits):
  data = np.hstack((Y[:, None], F))
  splitter = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = splits).split(data)

  penalty_errors = np.zeros(len(penalty_list))

  for p, penalty in enumerate(penalty_list):
    estimator = Lasso(alpha = penalty, normalize = False)
    cv_error = np.zeros(splits)
    i = 0

    for train, test in splitter:
      F_train, F_test = F[train], F[test]
      Y_train, Y_test = Y[train], Y[test]
      Y_hat = estimator.fit(F_train, Y_train).predict(F_test)
      cv_error[i] = r2_score(Y_test, Y_hat)
      i = i +1
      print('in loop')

    penalty_errors[p] = np.mean(cv_error)
    print('Penalty', penalty, penalty_errors[p])

  best = penalty_list[np.argmin(penalty_errors)]

  return(best, penalty_errors)
```

in which `np` stands for numpy. The print statements are only for checking what the code is doing. I'm only interested on the best penalty from an user-specified penalty list (list of floats) and on the final average error for each penalty value, stored on the array `penalty_errors`. However, when I run this function, I get the following behavior:

```
In [64]: optimal_penalty(Y, F, [0.5, 1, 2], 5)
in loop
in loop
in loop
in loop
in loop
Penalty 0.5 0.02312207752945177
Penalty 1 0.0
Penalty 2 0.0
Out[64]: (1, array([0.02312208, 0.        , 0.        ]))
```

As one can see, the code works as expected for the first value in the `penalty_list`. However, it seems that for other values of the penalty parameter, nothing is being computed at all since I see no "in loop" statements. Can you guys spot any silly mistake? I have just started with Python and I'm probably missing something here. Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: `splitter` is an iterator. once you've exhausted it of iterations (on the first loop) calling it again will immediately yield a `StopIteration` exception. you should create `splitter` on every iteration of the outside loop.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron! I didn't know this property about iterators. How memory consuming is to create ```splitter``` on every single run? Isn't it better, then, to create a list of elements from ```splitter``` and iterate over that list?

Comment: It's a time-space tradeoff. Creating a list of elements uses memory for all of them. An iterator uses only the memory for the current element, but it has to compute each one every time you use it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `splitter` works. It isn't necessarily making copies of the data, rather just a structure that points to the original data, so it might be a non-issue.

Comment: @Barmar well, *ideally* a *well implemented* iterator should. Not always the case, but usually it's a safe assumption. But there is nothing stoping someone  from doing something like `data_to_iterate = list(some_lazy_iterator); yield from data_to_iterate`